# Hide element "beneath" div of lower z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Two fiddles.  The first, showing everything working as I want: http://jsfiddle.net/3SWwD

The second, showing the problem as it exists on the site I'm trying to deploy the effect on: http://jsfiddle.net/3SWwD/1/

Those fiddles describe everything this code does, but for thoroughness:

I have two container divs bumped up to one another, the first of which contains an imagel which I have simplified to `<div id="image">` for this example.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="image"></div>
</div>
<div id="never_cover_me">
</div>
```

They are styled as follows, and theses styles will exhibit the issue, which I'll explain when I show the js.

```
#container{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
}

#image{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 50;
}

#never_cover_me {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Lastly, some Jquery/JS moves the image down, thus into the space of `#never_cover_me`.  If all was well in the world, `#image` would be covered by `#never_cover_me` while it was moved down, but since `#container` has a higher z-index than `#never_cover_me`, obviously that isn't the case and the image is instead drawn over `#never_cover_me`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(
         function(){
            $('#image').animate({top: '+=200px'}, "slow", function(){
                $('#image').delay(1000).animate({top: '-=200px'}, "slow")
            });
         },3000
    );
});
```

For various reasons, `#container` MUST have a higher z-index than `#never_cover_me`.  Semantically, I would prefer if `#image` stays within `#container`.

Ideas?

Comment: If the first one works, can't you just swap the current code with the existing code on the site...?

Comment: As I say at the bottom, for various reasons the z-index of `#container` must be higher than `#never_cover_me`.  The addition of that caveat in the second fiddle is what breaks it.

Comment: If you visualize this in 3d your #container would be in front of never_cover_me but what you are asking is that #container should be behind. Even if you break the image off the container you'll never achieve the effect. Just visualize it in real world. The only way it can be achieved is if never_cover_me has higher z-index than container.

Comment: Then you are trying to create an Escher Cascade since you want #container being higher than `#never_cover_me` and `#image` (which is inside `#container`), being lower than `#never_cover_me`. What if you take `#image` outside of #container?

Comment: Sorry if I made it seem like I wanted to force the heights to be different.  I was thinking about maybe a pseudo element that was invisible but which I could use to hide the element, I need to achieve the APPEARANCE of the image going behind the `#never_cover_me`, not to actually put it behind it.  Anyways, I solved it.  See my answer in a moment.

Comment: That was my bad, the question was asked poorly, now that I'm looking at it the way you were.

Comment: Upvoted for great fiddles and formatting the question well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#container`:

```
z-index: 200;
```

is above `#never_cover_me`:

```
z-index: 100;
```

Therefore, it is causing the issue you are experiencing. Here is more information on stacking order and how descendants are affected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_and_float

You shouldn't really try to use other elements to hide your content. A better solution would be to set `overflow:hidden;` on `#container` because the effect you are going for is "hide this when the block is outside the current element."

Comment: That's the better way to say it, yes.

Answer (score 2):

It was as easy as adding `overflow:hidden` to `#container`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3SWwD/2/